# Auto-coloring and auto-sorting macro Excel 2010

Tags: vba, sorting, excel

Good afternoon,

I need assistance with the following item.

I am trying to find a macro that both auto-sorts and auto-colors based on input.

For example, I have three columns. In the first column, I enter the genotype for a gene of interest. Using a VLOOKUP sheet in the same excel, the entry would return the equivalent phenotype for that gene in the second column. The final column, third column, would then return how this phenotype affects the disease state (e.g. Normal = Green, Slow = Yellow, Fast = Red).

Let us say this is what our original spreadsheet appeared as:

```
Genotype    Phenotype    Disease State 
XX          IM           Slow
YY          UM           Fast
XY          EM           Normal
YY          UM           Fast
```

Once the auto-coloring and auto-sorting completes its task, this table should read:

```
Genotype    Phenotype    Disease State
XY          EM           Normal
XX          IM           Slow
YY          UM           Fast
YY          UM           Fast
```

I have found macros where they auto-sort, or auto-color alone, but when I've tried combining these macros, I keep getting errors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

These are the macros I've been trying out. The auto-sort works perfectly, but the auto-coloring I am having trouble with. The errors I get range, and sometimes nothing happens.

For auto-sorting:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("A1").Sort Key1:=Range("A2"), _
          Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes, _
          OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
          Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
    End If
End Sub
```

For auto-coloring:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Column <> 1 Then Exit Sub
If Target.Row < 1 Then Exit Sub
Select Case LCase(Target.Value)
    Case "Normal"
        Target.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    Case "Fast"
        Target.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    Case "Slow"
        Target.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 5
        Target.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexAutomatic
End Select
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Sub changeApplicationEnableEvents2truee()
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You say you've gotten errors, can you post the code you've tried so we can see what you're doing??

Comment: Hi John, added the codes. The errors have ranged, and in some cases nothing really has happened. Auto-sorting on its own works great, but the auto-coloring I'm having trouble with. And when I've tried adding auto-coloring to the same sheet as auto-coloring, I get a "ambiguous name detected" error. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a functioning Auto-Sort macro, you could use that and then try some [Conditional Formatting](http://office.microsoft.com/en-nz/excel-help/add-change-find-or-clear-conditional-formats-HP010073939.aspx) to set the colours.

Comment: Hi Rick, Auto-sorting macro does work fine. They prefer the whole thing being automated, rather than manual conditional formatting. Unless you're referring to a macro that does the conditional formatting? Thank you.

Comment: Conditional formatting is automated. You can just set the rules on the range of cells that need to be formatted and the colour will change based on the value in a cell.

Answer (score 0):

As @pnuts said, one problem is that you seem to have 2 Worksheet_Change routines. There were a few issues with your color changing code: using LCase() forced your string values to all lower case; only the changed row was getting its color changed, rather than the entire resorted range; etc.

I made some minimal changes to what you had. Does this produce the result you're looking for?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim rng As Range


    On Error Resume Next
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("A1").Sort Key1:=Range("A2"), _
          Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes, _
          OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
          Orientation:=xlTopToBottom

        For Each rng In Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("A:A")).Cells

            If Not IsEmpty(rng) Then

                Select Case rng.Offset(, 2).Value
                Case "Normal"
                    rng.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbGreen
                Case "Fast"
                    rng.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbRed
                Case "Slow"
                    rng.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbYellow
                Case Else
                    rng.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
                End Select
            End If
        Next rng
    End If

End Sub
```